# HDD SMART Caution changed to Good

Tags: hard-drive, smart, crystaldiskinfo

This is a strange happening. I had a disk whose SMART status was displayed as Caution in CrystalDiskInfo when I powered it up after a few years. It had uncorrectable sector and pending sectors, and and some files were corrupt. I downloaded the Seagate utility (the disk was a Seagate) and executed Long Fix All. After running it for about 6 hours, when I re-ran CrystalDiskInfo, its status became Good. There still was the uncorrectable sector count, and about 22 rellocated sector count, etc, but the status was blue Good. Who or what determines if the status is good or bad? CrystalDiskInfo or the disk itself? And can a Caution disk really become Good again?

Comment: it depends on whether the failures are hard or soft. in this case it appears that CDI rated the disk as caution, because it didn't know whether the pending clusters could be recovered. with a disk check, those pending sectors were successfully reallocated, and your reallocated sector count is below the warning level, so the disk went back to green.  personally, I'd treat the disk with caution regardless, as bad sectors tend to grow exponentially, so keep a watch on pending sectors to see if the issue is continuing.

Comment: The disk itself determines if its good.  SMART is useful but not infallible.

Comment: davidgo, that is wrong. Read here: https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/crystaldiskinfo-health-status/
There is no global oversimplified health status coming from the disk. Crystal Disk Info is constructing that artifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystaldiskinfo is determining the health status itself:

https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/crystaldiskinfo-health-status/

Although the underlying attributes matter I consider this as a oversimplification as there are other attributes to take into account as well.

What about a disk showing a maximum temperature of 60°C?
What about a disk showing three crashes?

There is no alternative to looking at the whole list of attributes and watching them move over time.